# Android ListView, adding items from database in listview

Tags: android

I have a process in which a user selects a city, then sees medical practitioners in that state.

I have results that show the name of the medical practice:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();



        final String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");

        String location = b.getString("selectedItems");



        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_PRACTICE_NAME);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                if (e == null) {
                    // Success
                    //store users variable in Parse to mMidwifeLocations
                    mMidwives = users;
                    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    //mMidwifeType = ParseUser.getString("usertype");

                    //store users in string array, locations
                    String[] midwives = new String[mMidwives.size()];
                    String[] locations = new String[mMidwives.size()];
                    String check;
                    String location;

                    int i = 0;
                    for(ParseUser user : mMidwives) {
                        //get city value from user, assign it to check variable

                        location = user.getString("city");

                        check = user.getString("userType");

                        if (!Arrays.asList(midwives).contains(check) && type != "patient" && Arrays.asList(resultArr).contains(location) ) {

                            //in locations array, assign practiename values
                                midwives[i] = user.getString("practicename");


                        }
                    }
                    i++;
```

I also want to return in the list the primary contact, address, and practice philosophy..what is the best strategy to do this?  I am using a simple_list_item_1 list type...there are other list types...wondering if using one of those might be the answer..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you probably want to do all of this inside the onCreate() method.

Im not to sure if this is what you want but from what i understand i am writing this.

I would personally write down all the data you want in a string-array in your strings.XML

```
<string-array name="string_array">
<item name ="item1"> item1 </item>
.......
</string-array>
```

Then I would just grab that data and sort it in order of what order your states are in. So they would match. But by looking at what you have done you have done that with ease

Then creating a custom layout assign each string to it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change this layout how you would like to see your data, also add more textviews to how many you would need.

Now you would need to create a adapter for this listview.

```
 class adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SingleRow> arrayList;
    Context context;

    adapter(Context contxt) {
        context = contxt;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        Resources res = contxt.getResources();
        String[] items= res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {//Change the 1 in i < 1 to how big your list is.
            arrayList.add(new SingleRow(items[i]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout, parent, false);
        TextView item1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtItem1);
        SingleRow temp = arrayList.get(position);
        items.setText(temp.items);

        return row;
    }
}

class SingleRow {
    String items;
    SingleRow(String items) {
        this.items = items;

    }
}
```

After reading the code and analyzing it you would figure out how to add data to the textviews for each row item, and do so by how many you will need.

Now you will have to set the adapter to the listview by...

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
listView.setAdapter(new adapter(getActivity()));
```

Now you should be able to make a custom listview layout. If any problems occur please just comment on this answer and ill try to fix it.

Good luck.

Comment: just to clarify; right now I am passing in a city selected in a previous activity, and, in OnResume, I am looping through data to find all medical practices in the selected city, and the adapter is pushing this result to the listview...your solution here seems to have an adapter that pulls information from a layout that is not a listview, but converts that layout to a listview?  I would still want the results limited by the query. So I would place the adapter code where I have my current adapter, which is now simply pulling practice names based on city?

Comment: I figured this out, but in case anyone else searching wants a detailed description of this, this is a good source https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView